# In BlackBerry UI Right Align Issue

Tags: blackberry

In BlackBerry UI I am trying to align some LabelFields Right aligned and left aligned:

For this I have created one VertiFieldManager at top level then Adding a HorizontalFieldmanager to it  and all lalbelFields are added to horizontalFieldManager,

Horizontal field Manager is forcing content to Left aligned.
How can I align the fields in Right side?

I tried spacing but it does not looks good in BB devices having different  Pixcels resolution.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

i'm still new on BB, but have you tried to change Long style for the HorizontalField ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code -

```
JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager j=new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager(new NullField(),your_field, true);
add(j);
```

//JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager  class is given below.

```
public class JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager extends Manager
{
    private static final int SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT = 32;

public Field _leftField;
public Field _rightField;

private boolean _giveLeftFieldPriority;

public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( Field leftField, Field rightField, boolean giveLeftFieldPriority )
{
    this( leftField, rightField, giveLeftFieldPriority, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH );
}

public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( Field leftField, Field rightField, boolean giveLeftFieldPriority, long style )
{
    super( style );

    _leftField = leftField;
    _rightField = rightField;

    add( _leftField );
    add( _rightField );

    _giveLeftFieldPriority = giveLeftFieldPriority;
}

public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( boolean giveLeftFieldPriority, long style )
{
    super( style );
    _giveLeftFieldPriority = giveLeftFieldPriority;
}

public void addLeftField( Field field )
{
    if( _leftField != null ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    _leftField = field;
    add( _leftField );
}

public void addRightField( Field field )
{
    if( _rightField != null ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    _rightField = field;
    add( _rightField );
}

public int getPreferredWidth()
{
    return _leftField.getPreferredWidth() + _rightField.getPreferredWidth();
}

public int getPreferredHeight()
{
    return Math.max( _leftField.getPreferredHeight(), _rightField.getPreferredHeight() );
}

protected void sublayout( int width, int height )
{
    Field firstField;
    Field secondField;
    if( _giveLeftFieldPriority ) {
        firstField = _leftField;
        secondField = _rightField;
    } else {
        firstField = _rightField;
        secondField = _leftField;
    }

    int maxHeight = 0;

    int availableWidth = width;
    availableWidth -= _leftField.getMarginLeft();
    availableWidth -= Math.max( _leftField.getMarginRight(), _rightField.getMarginLeft() );
    availableWidth -= _rightField.getMarginRight();

    layoutChild( firstField, availableWidth, height - firstField.getMarginTop() - firstField.getMarginBottom() );
    maxHeight = Math.max( maxHeight, firstField.getMarginTop() + firstField.getHeight() + firstField.getMarginBottom() );
    availableWidth -= firstField.getWidth();

    layoutChild( secondField, availableWidth, height - secondField.getMarginTop() - secondField.getMarginBottom() );
    maxHeight = Math.max( maxHeight, secondField.getMarginTop() + secondField.getHeight() + secondField.getMarginBottom() );
    availableWidth -= secondField.getWidth();

    if( !isStyle( Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT ) ) {
        height = maxHeight;
    }
    if( !isStyle( Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH ) ) {
        width -= availableWidth;
    }

    setPositionChild( _leftField, _leftField.getMarginLeft(), getFieldY( _leftField, height ) );
    setPositionChild( _rightField, width - _rightField.getWidth() - _rightField.getMarginRight(), getFieldY( _rightField, height ) );

    setExtent( width, height );
}

private int getFieldY( Field field, int height )
{
    switch( (int)( ( field.getStyle() & FIELD_VALIGN_MASK ) >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ) ) {
        case (int)( FIELD_BOTTOM >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ):
            return height - field.getHeight() - field.getMarginBottom();
        case (int)( FIELD_VCENTER >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ):
            return field.getMarginTop() + ( height - field.getMarginTop() - field.getHeight() - field.getMarginBottom() ) / 2;
        default:
            return field.getMarginTop();
    }
}


public Field getLeftField()
{
    return _leftField;
}

public Field getRightField()
{
    return _rightField;
}

public void replace( Field oldField, Field newField )
{
    if( oldField == newField ) {
        // Nothing to do
        return;
    }

    if( oldField == _leftField ) {
        _leftField = newField;
    } else if( oldField == _rightField ) {
        _rightField = newField;
    }
    add( newField );
    delete( oldField );
}



}
```

Comment: IMHO, you should specify where you get the `JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager' from.

Comment: its a custom class. 'From where you get it'- that doesn't matter. Its helpful for you is important.

Comment: It's not custom. It is an exact copy of `JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager` that is part of BlackBerry's advanced UI library (http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/About_the_advanced_UI_library_1626501_11.jsp). I think they deserve the credit.

Comment: ya. All credits goes to Blackberry. i didn't said that its my code. its a custom class of blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

There are no nice solution unfortunately. The smaller than previous I think this:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

LabelField leftField = new LabelField("One");
hfm.add(leftField);

LabelField rightField = new LabelField("Two", LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.RIGHT);
hfm.add(rightField);
```

Basically we use all available width area for second field and ask it to draw text as right aligned.
This solution is Ok because LabeLField is not focusable. As soon as you have to deal with focusable fields use solution from @Signare.